# Why can't I craft a notch apple now?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I put eight gold blocks and an apple in a crafting table, but no notch apple appeared.

Why is this so? I thought it was always there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After Minecraft 1.9, this recipe was removed, probably because it was rather OP, and gold blocks could be easily obtained by a gold farm. If you want more "Notch" apples, you may have to downgrade Minecraft to 1.8, and come back to 1.16 or whatever version you are using.

Comment: but i found them in chests, so they can't be removed right

Comment: @DarthOverlord What fasterthanlight is saying, is that the ***recipe*** was removed, not the Notch apple itself. This means they can no longer be crafted, but - as you've witnessed first-hand - they still can be obtained from other sources, like treasure chests.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there is no such thing as 'downgrading'. If you open a 1.16 world in 1.8 it is guaranteed to break a lot of things (if it doesn't outright crash).

Answer (score 3):

The Enchanted Golden Apple (also known as *"God Apple"* or just *"Gapple"*) had their crafting recipe removed in Java Edition 1.9, [more precisely in 15w44a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_15w44a).

> - *Enchanted golden apples can no longer be crafted.* - [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_15w44a#Items_2)

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple way to bypass it though, with the use of datapacks, go to vannilatweaks.com and the crafting tweaks section has a craft able notch apple datapack

Comment: Darth Overlord is asking **why** it was gone, not how to bypass it.